# CakePHP3でのPOSTリクエストの処理

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP3で以下のスクリプトからリクエストされるパラメータ
id及びparamを取得したいのですがどのように受け取ればよいのでしょうか。
送信側

```
---Python---
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

p = {"id":0, "param" : "dammy" }

print requests.post('http://localhost/testApp/testApp.json',data=p).text
```

受け取り側

```
---Cakephp(testAppController.php)---
public function index()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $name = $this->request->data();
        // name が null になってしまう
        $this->set(compact('name'));
    }
...
}
```

Comment: POSTデータの取得は、`$this->request->data()`で合っています。`$_POST`のダンプ結果はどうなっていますか？また、この例だとリクエストURLは`http://localhost/testApp/index.json`ではありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
上記ソースの ...　の部分に以下の未定義変数hogeを指定しているコードがあり、
実行が失敗していたので nullとなっておりました。
$this->set('_serialize',['hoge']);
この行をコメントアウトしたところ正しく、jsonが返却されました。